# Iterate an array in a shell script to save its values in a .plist and a .db

Tags: bash, shell

This shell script allows to programmatically save text replacements for macOS, on both `GlobalPreferences.plist` and `UserDictionary.db`.

```
date=$(date +%s)
while read -r replace with; do
    plist+="{on=1;replace=\"$replace\";with=\"$with\";},"
    sql+="INSERT INTO 'ZUSERDICTIONARYENTRY' VALUES($((++i)),1,1,0,0,0,0,$date,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,\"$with\",\"$replace\",NULL);"
done < <(sed 's/\\/\\\\/g;s/"/\\"/g' ~/replacements.txt)
sqlite3 ~/Library/Dictionaries/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/$USER~*/UserDictionary/local/store/UserDictionary.db "delete from ZUSERDICTIONARYENTRY;$sql"
defaults write -g NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems "(${plist%?})"
```

How can I customize it so that it can read a previously declared array, instead of a `~/replacements.txt` external file?

Comment: What are the contents of `~/replacements.txt` and how is your array going to store the contents? same as the file? Give a minimal verifiable input and expected output.

Comment: The `sh` tag doesn't belong here at all -- this code is not POSIX sh compliant.

Comment: ...that said, I'm not sure we need `~/replacements.txt`, but we **definitely** need to know what the array looks like. For instance, is it an associative array, ie. `declare -A replacements=( [replace]="with" )`? Is it a numerically-indexed array? If so, how are the key and values distinguished? etc, etc, etc.

Comment: ...and in terms of string concatenation to generate SQL, just no. Or, to put it a bit more verbosely: Use a language with a database library having bind variable support. Python's db-api does, and the `sqlite3` library is shipped with recent Python interpreters in-the-box by default.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy Here's the page where I grabbed this code: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124048/where-is-the-replace-with-list-stored I tried to customize it to use a simple array without any luck

Comment: Again, how are you populating that "simple array"? If you use `declare -p replacements` (for your array named `replacements`), that will print it in a way that's entirely unambiguous; could you do that here, to provide sample data? To be clear, what I'm worried about is the potential that you may be running `replacements=( $(cat ...) )` or `replacements=( $(curl ...) )`, and thereby getting side effects by way of string-splitting and globbing, rather than using one of the two safe ways of populating the array given in my answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy My idea was to manually specify an array at the top, something like [{ on=1; replace=\"a\"; with=\"b\"; }, { on=1; replace=\"c\"; with=\"d\"; }].

Comment: ...so in **plist** form, not in bash-array form? I mean, we *could* teach your code how to parse a plist, but that's a fair bit of work. Easier to specify a native bash array, and generate both outputs from that.

Comment: For my existing answer, you'd want `replacements=( "a b" "c d" )`, or the like.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy A bash array would be perfect! Sorry for the confusing example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming (and these are large and unfounded assumptions, necessary due to the vagueness of the question) that your array contains one entry per line of the input file:

---

Replace

```
sed 's/\\/\\\\/g;s/"/\\"/g' ~/replacements.txt
```

with:

```
printf '%s\n' "${replacements[@]}" | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g;s/"/\\"/g'
```

---

To be clear, this is assuming a numerically-indexed array. For instance, you could generate such an array from your `replacements.txt` with:

```
# in bash 4.0 or newer
mapfile -t replacements <~/replacements.txt
```

...or:

```
# in bash 3.x or newer
replacements=( )
while IFS= read -r line; do replacements+=( "$line" ); done <~/replacements.txt
```